# How do you implement PermissionAwareActivity for react native?

Tags: java, android, react-native

There is very little documentation on react native's [`PermissionAwareActivity`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/core/PermissionAwareActivity.java) and I need to implement its methods for Android API 23+ to allow the user to accept / decline bluetooth permissions.

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat; 
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionAwareActivity;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionListener;
public class MainActivity extends ExponentActivity implements PermissionAwareActivity {

  private PermissionListener mPermissionListener;

  @Override
  public int checkPermission(String permission, int pid, int uid) {
    return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
  }

  @Override
  public  int checkSelfPermission(String permission) {
    return PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
  }

  @Override
  public void requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode, PermissionListener listener) {
    mPermissionListener = listener;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, requestCode);
  }


  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    // callback to native module
    mPermissionListener.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }
  ...
```

I'm not really sure how I'm suppose to implement these methods. Any help is appreciated. Even if someone can point me to some documentation or resource which I cannot find.

Comment: Why not use the `PermissionsAndroid` from `react-native`?

Comment: @VojtaNovak You have to implement its methods in Android for it to work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean (?), I've been using `PermissionsAndroid` successfully. No need to implement anything.

Comment: @AdrianCarolli, did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: Something else I found, but according to the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html) "This API only works in projects made with react-native init or in those made with Create React Native App which have since ejected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this issue while adding react native in existing Android application. Fixed this by implementing following methods in ReactActivity.java

```
@Override
public void requestPermissions(
        String[] permissions, int requestCode, PermissionListener listener) {
    mDelegate.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode, listener);
}


protected @Nullable String getMainComponentName() {
        return null;
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(
        int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    mDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

import followings

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionAwareActivity;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionListener;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

change from this

```
implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler
```

to this

```
implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler, PermissionAwareActivity
```

For more details see [ReactActivity.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivity.java) official repo

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using an activity that is not derived my ReactActivity and needs to be permission aware, add the following to your activity:

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionAwareActivity;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.PermissionListener;

....

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements PermissionAwareActivity {
    private PermissionListener permissionListener;

   ....


       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode, PermissionListener listener) {
        permissionListener = listener;
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (permissionListener != null && permissionListener.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)) {
            permissionListener = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I got the code from [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/784#issuecomment-338824333). Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47309529/201828).

Comment: I needed just a part of this onRequestPermissionsResult and it worked, but I needed to make a copy of permissionListener because compiler was shouting

Answer (score 1):

I found the default implementation of the `PermissionAwareActivity` in the [React-Native source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivity.java).

However that file has a lot of other boilerplate code mixed in, so I'm not sure which specific pieces are required for implementation.

The better alternative seems to be to have your `MainActivity` inherit from `ReactActivity`. It looks like you're inheriting from `ExponentActivity`. I'm not sure what that is, but if it's a custom Activity subclass that you have control over you should be able to have that inherit from `ReactActivity`.