# Permissions API and PermissionAwareActivity

Tags: react-native

I try to build a BLE app with expokit. This part of code is throwing me this error: `Error: Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity.`
How am i supposed to fix this?

I've tested it in an android device, can't test this on iOS.

```
PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then((result) => {
  if (result) {
    console.log("User accept");
  } else {
     console.log("User refuse");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/784#issuecomment-338824333) but If someone has a solution without touching at native code it could be way better.