# How can a Rust application on Android request permissions like READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, rust, android-ndk

I have a Rust application for Android and it needs to be able to read files on the external storage.

If I just naively run

```
let f = File::open("/sdcard/tmp/demo.ts");
error!("FILE CHECK {:?}", f);
```

I get

```
2023-07-12 10:46:24.150 1905-12170/? E/MediaProvider: Permission to access file: /storage/emulated/0/tmp/demo.ts is denied
2023-07-12 10:46:24.151 10285-10308/rust.openxr_gst E/openxr_gst: FILE CHECK Err(Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" })
```

In the logs.

The Java version of our application does

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 1);
}
```

plus an `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback to handle the answer from the pop-up.

What API should a Rust application use?

Comment: To my knowledge you have to execute the same Java/Kotlin methods via Java Native Access (JNI).

Comment: I wonder how to tap into the onRequestPermissionsResult callback of the NativeActivity...

Comment: You have no option but to subclass NativeActivity. But you can keep the Java code to a minimum by taking a page from React Native, which has a [`requestPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode, PermissionListener listener)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567136/1548468) method

Answer (score 0):

I made some progress by avoiding ActivityCompat.  A coworker pointed out that `android.content.ContextWrapper` has `checkSelfPermission()` and `android.app.Activity` has `requestPermissions()` .

I dusted off my jni_boilerplate crate and made the calls.

Unfortunately, the confirmation pop-up did not appear in my VR headset.  The scene continued to render, but the Quest 2's touch controllers sampled as "inactive".  The controller sampling as inactive is similar to the behavior in a mixed java/rust app that does display the pop-up.  I am missing some mysterious logic that lets the OS display the pop-up over my rendered scene.