# How can a Rust application based on android-activity access classes (like ActivityCompat) from auxiliary packages?

Tags: android, rust, android-ndk

I have a rust native android application based on the `android-activity` .  Based on some comments to [How can a Rust application on Android request permissions like READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76671942/how-can-a-rust-application-on-android-request-permissions-like-read-external-sto?noredirect=1#comment135179518_76671942)  I would like to call `ActivityCompat.requestPermission()` , but when I call `jni_env.find_class("androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat")` I get an exception.  I can call `jni_env.find_class("java/lang/String")` and it gives me an `Ok(JClass(JObject { internal: 0x111, lifetime: PhantomData<&()> }))`

My current hypothesis is that the ActivityCompat class comes from a jar file that is not being included in the android-activity wrapper.

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "check2"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
android-activity = { version = "*", features = ["native-activity"] }
android_logger = "*"
jni="0.19.0"
ndk-context="*"
log="*"

[lib]
crate-type = ["lib", "cdylib"]

[package.metadata.android]
apk_label = "demonstration of missing java class"
target_sdk_version = 29
min_sdk_version = 29
#runtime_libs = "libs"

[[package.metadata.android.application.activity.intent_filter]]
actions = ["android.intent.action.MAIN"]
categories = [
    "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER",
]
```

`lib.rs`:

```
use android_activity::AndroidApp;
use jni::errors::Error;
use jni::JavaVM;
use log::debug;
use std::ffi::c_void;

pub fn adapt_android_env() -> Result<(JavaVM, *mut c_void), Error> {
    let ctx = ndk_context::android_context();
    let vm = unsafe { jni::JavaVM::from_raw(ctx.vm().cast()) }?;
    let activity = ctx.context();

    Ok((vm, activity))
}

#[no_mangle]
fn android_main(_android_app: AndroidApp) {
    android_logger::init_once(
        android_logger::Config::default().with_max_level(log::LevelFilter::Trace),
    );

    debug!("application starting");

    let (jvm, _activity) = adapt_android_env().unwrap();
    let jni_env = jvm.attach_current_thread().unwrap();

    //

    {
        let x = jni_env.find_class("java/lang/String");
        debug!("java class string is {:?}", x);
    }
    {
        let x = jni_env.find_class("androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat");
        debug!("java class ActivityCompat is {:?}", x);
    }

    debug!("exception state is {:?}", jni_env.exception_check());
    debug!("exception clear is {:?}", jni_env.exception_clear());

    debug!("application ending");
}
```

How do I adjust my code to access the ActivityCompat class?

Comment: The `androidx` classes are not a part of Android itself. Did you include the necessary androidx library as a dependency in your build? (probably `androidx.core`, or possibly `androidx.appcompat`)?

Comment: As a side note, I believe your `_android_app` object has an `activity` member which in turn holds a `JNIEnv*` that you can use (at least as long as you're on the same thread).